# Property lazy initialization vs Core Data run in main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *emails;
```

and a lazy initializer for it

```
- (NSArray *) emails
{
    if (_emails == nil) {
        CoreDataElement* cde = [user grabCoreDataElement];
        _emails = [cde.emails allObjects];
    }
    return _emails;
 }
```

However during a code review it was pointed out that access to Core Data should be done in the main thread.

So I was thinking in modifying the initializer to:

```
- (NSArray *) emails
{
    if (_emails == nil) {
        if (NSThread isMainThread])
        {
            CoreDataElement* cde = [user grabCoreDataElement];
            _emails = [cde.emails allObjects];
        }
        else
        {
            __block NSArray *result = nil;
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                result = self.emails;
            });
            return result;
        }
    }
    return _emails;
```

}

So my questions are:

- (1) Is the MainThread enforcement necessary?
- (2) Is the above code a canonical way to handle lazy initializers and core data object access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those are right. If you're using Core Data and may have code running on multiple threads, the correct way to do it is to use either `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` when creating your managed object context, and then to use either `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` whenever you do anything that accesses Core Data. Checking `NSThread` or using `dispatch_sync` might not break at first but both violate Core Data's idea of how it should work.

With this approach, the code in your method would be wrapped in a call to `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`, **but that's not all**. You need to use those methods any time you access Core Data in any way-- so if you're returning an array of managed objects, you need to use those same block calls when you look up values on those objects.